# Soft Delete Cascading with Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel, soft-delete

I'm trying to implement soft deleting in Laravel.

Here are my relationships

```
Tournament ( hasMany ) CategoryTournament (hasOne) CategorySettings
Tournament ( hasMany ) CategoryTournament (belongsToMany) CategoryTournamentUser
```

So, I used [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31456804/laravel-5-cascade-soft-delete) that help me a lot

Now, when I SoftDelete a Tournament, all CategoryTournaments related are also deleted.

But then, I tried to apply it recursively, so I wrote the same code in CategoryTournament Model:

```
static::deleting(function($categoryTournament) {
        $categoryTournament->settings()->delete();
        $categoryTournament->users()->delete();
    });
```

But this code is never ran.
I checked that I have settings and user to delete, but none of them are soft deleted...

Did I miss something??? It should work!

EDIT:

Now, I am trying to Soft Delete a User, it is just one more level:

```
User (HasMany) Tournament ( hasMany ) CategoryTournament (hasOne) CategorySettings
```

So now, when I soft Delete user, it delete his tournaments, but it doesn't delete anymore his CategoryTournaments, so this is not a config error.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Inside your `static boot` method you have to iterate through your `toMany` relations.

F.a:

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

class Tournament extends Model
{
  use SoftDeletes;

  public function categoryTournament() {
    return $this->hasMany(CategoryTournament::class);
  }

  protected static function boot() {
    parent::boot();

    static::deleting(function($tournament) {
      foreach ($tournament->categoryTournament()->get() as $ct) {
        $ct->delete();
      }
    });
  }
}
```

The other files should look like this:

`CategoryTournament.php`

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

class CategoryTournament extends Model
{
  use SoftDeletes;

  public function tournament() {
    return $this->belongsTo(Tournament::class);
  }

  public function settings() {
    return $this->belongsTo(Settings::class);
  }

  protected static function boot() {
    parent::boot();

    static::deleting(function($categoryTournament) {
      var_dump('categoryTournament');
      $categoryTournament->settings()->delete();
    });
  }
}
```

`Settings.php`

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

class Settings extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes;

    public function categoryTournament() {
      return $this->hasOne(CategoryTournament::class);
    }

    protected static function boot() {
    parent::boot();

    static::deleting(function($settings) {
      var_dump('settings');
    });
  }
}
```

`Migration`

```
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateTables extends Migration
{
  /**
   * Run the migrations.
   *
   * @return void
   */
  public function up() {

    Schema::create('tournaments', function (Blueprint $table) {
      $table->increments('id');
      $table->timestamps();
      $table->softDeletes();
    });

    Schema::create('settings', function (Blueprint $table) {
      $table->increments('id');
      $table->timestamps();
      $table->softDeletes();
    });

    Schema::create('category_tournaments', function (Blueprint $table) {
      $table->increments('id');
      $table->integer('tournament_id')->unsigned();
      $table->integer('settings_id')->unsigned();
      $table->timestamps();
      $table->softDeletes();

      $table->foreign('tournament_id')->references('id')->on('tournaments');
      $table->foreign('settings_id')->references('id')->on('settings');
    });
  }

  /**
   * Reverse the migrations.
   *
   * @return void
   */
  public function down() {

    Schema::drop('category_tournaments');
    Schema::drop('settings');
    Schema::drop('tournaments');
  }
}
```

Comment: it worked! Why should I use a foreach??? without foreach, it was deleting well categoryTournament!

Comment: I just had to repeat the same foreach in all model, include it so that I accept your answer!

Comment: it seems, that the deleting event is only getting fired if you delete each model explicitly. If you have the time, look up how the events work.

Comment: According to the Laravel documentation, the records are not actually retrieved when performing a mass delete