# eloquent events, can I use them in model class?

Tags: laravel

I am reading up on laravel softdelete and restore cascade here: [Laravel 5: cascade soft delete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31456804/laravel-5-cascade-soft-delete)

where a user said:

```
You should use Eloquent events for this.

Offers::deleted(function($offer) {
    $offer->services()->delete();
});
Offers::restored(function($offer) {
    $offer->services()->withTrashed()->restore();
});
```

He did not mention where to place this code, I am interested in listening for eloquent deleted and restored events. Where can I put this code? Can I listen for it in the model class? If not where to place it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think...

```
<?php
class Attribute extends Model implements Transformable
{
//....
protected static function boot() {
    parent::boot();

    static::deleting(function($model) {
        foreach ($model->attributeValue()->get() as $attributeValue) {
            $attributeValue->delete();
        }
    });

}
```

Or example:

```
class BaseModel extends Model
{
    public static function boot()
    {
        static::creating(function ($model) {
        // blah blah
        });

        static::updating(function ($model) {
        // bleh bleh
        });

        static::deleting(function ($model) {
        // bluh bluh
        });

       parent::boot();
   }
}
```